# Tesseract training files folder for iOS application

Tags: ios, app-store, tesseract, data-storage

Where I should put Tesseract's training data (~34MB) for my iOS application to comply Apple's storage Guideline?

I do not know why but many examples from the Internet copy these files under /Document folder.

Does it comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines?

Apple rejected my application twice :

```
             1) In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your  
                app  stores 34.4MB. To check how much data your app is storing:

                    - Install and launch your app
                    - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage

            2) Moved training files from /Document to /Library folder :

                  We have found upon downloading the application and launching it, 
                  that the storage is 34.4MB. 
                  The application should not store over 2MB of data unless user 
                  generated. It would be appropriate to revise the content.
```

Where I should place Tessaract's training files to comply Apple's policy?